# Referencing where a child object goes using deepcopy in Python

Tags: python, deep-copy

A question about deepcopy in Python:

I have a class A which contains a list of objects from class B, and a class C which contains a list of objects from class A.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(S):
        self.S = set(S)

class B(object):
    def __init__(buddies):
        self.buddies = set(buddies)

class C(object):
    def __init__(L):
        self.L = set(L)
    def SplitA(a,b):
        left = deepcopy(a)
        left.S -= new_b.buddies
        right = A(new_b.buddies)
        L |= left
        L |= right
```

So I want C to have a Split function which, given an A object `a` and a B object `b` in `a.S`, will make two new A objects: one containing the 'buddies' of `b` (which are in `a.S`), one containing of the rest of `a.S`.

The problem is, I don't know how to figure out what the designated b becomes in the deepcopy.  In other words,

> how do I find `new_b` in the above code?

(Note: In my actual code it is important to do it in this order, i.e. adding `new_a` and then splitting `a` into `left` and `right` would not work.)

Comment: I assume you are using `deepcopy` because you want C to contain clones of the objects in A and B.

Comment: @Jonathan Yes, in other words I'd like to be able to manipulate the objects in `left` and `right` without affecting their counterparts in `a`.

Comment: (I should mention I have now solved the problem I was having by a somewhat hard-coded solution, but I am still interested in this answer for theoretical value.)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that the designated b does not become anything other than b in deep copy as you are not deep copying b at all.  So just replace `new_b` with `b` in your example.

Comment: I thought the point of deepcopy was that it made copies of all of a's data members, including a.S (and thus b).  Am I wrong about that?

Comment: It does __but__ only the such members of type B that are members of S that are a part of L - the b that you are talking about is a parameter of SplitA that hopefully is of type B - _you are not enforcing that_ - that may or may not have some (buddy) members in common with the a-L-S-buddies in a'-L'-S'-buddies' as I said above __you are not copying b_ you may be copying some members of type B somewhere down the chain.

Answer (score 0):

This code should do what you were looking for.

```
from copy import deepcopy


class A(object):
    def __init__(self, S):
        self.S = set(S)


class B(object):
    def __init__(self, buddies):
        self.buddies = set(buddies)


class C(object):
    def __init__(self, L):
        self.L = set(L)

    def SplitA(self, a, b):
        left = set()
        left -= b.buddies   # Since the objects in the sets are unchanged
                            # you can do a set difference that will leave you
                            # with only the members of a that are not in b
        left = deepcopy(left)  # Now get a deep copy of left
        right = deepcopy(b.S)  # and a deep copy of b.S
        self.L |= left      # and combine them
        self.L |= right
```